# Dropdown part of navbar displaying through other li elements when set to responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-lists, navigationbar

I have been trying to make my navbar responsive. So far I managed to display all li items underneath each other when the screen gets to small. However some li's of my navbar have sub items which normally drops down (Classes has 3 sub li's). When hovering one of the li's which has subitems it renders them through the main li items of the nav bar.

What I want is that the submenus dont get triggered by hovering, but only when the user taps their screen. Afterwards it should display the submenu items underneath the parent li and then continue with the other main li's.

The code underneath is the working part for the fullscreen nav bar.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qpp9Lhj5/)

```
.nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
border-bottom: none;
transition: .5s background-color;
}

.nav ul {
list-style: none;
background-color: #522d54;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: block;
}

.nav li {
font-family: 'Allerta', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width: auto;
line-height: 40px;
border-bottom: none;
font-size: 1em;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
}

.nav a:hover {
background-color: #39203b;
}

.nav a.active {
cursor: default;
background-color: #824885;
box-shadow: inset 0em -.2em #b084b3;
}

 .nav ul li {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li ul li {
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.nav li ul li a {
text-align: left;
font-size: .8em;
white-space: nowrap;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
display: block;
}

.nav ul li ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
width: inherit;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override your hover display with none, because you no longer want it to show on hover.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Then you will need to use javascript or jquery to add a class to the li on click:

jQuery could be something like (assumes you have class 'sub' on items with sub menus):

```
$('.nav li.sub').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open-sub-menu');
});
```

New class is:

```
.nav li.sub.open-sub-menu ul {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much that truly did the trick. I am a complete jquery/js noob so this was extremely helpful. Somehow it took me 15 minutes to figure out I had not linked to jquery in the head tags.

For those with the same problem as me make sure to put this in between the  tags of your html.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```